# What does a decimal number mean in the Avg. position report in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console

Do decimal numbers like 6.8 in the Avg. position report in Google Webmaster Tools mean that the URL appeared on page 6 in the 8th position?

If that is true, I am surprised that a searcher would actually go that far into an organic search (e.g., a 6.7 actually got 11 clicks).

What would an even number mean then (e.g., a 17 or 20)?

Comment: AFAIK that decimal positions are indicating the google map listings(google place), some time thst listing will show for a query and some times not, thats why you got a clicks for the decimal positions. let me know if it is not clear, i will reply tommrow with example.

Answer (score 2):

It shows an *average* of positions on the result page (i.e., the sum of positions divided by number of impressions). Whole numbers mean that there was only one impression, or the average computes to an integer. See [this](http://moz.com/ugc/testing-the-accuracy-of-avg-position-for-search-queries-in-google-webmaster-tools) Moz Blog for more information.

Beware - averages of ordinal values (i.e., ranks) are not what they actually appear to be. SERP positions are ordinals - they don't have a normal value distribution.

The sum of traffic from positions 1 + 5 does not equal the traffic of (3+3 or 2+4), but all have an average of 3. In fact the value drops off exponentially (it also varies a lot with query type etc).

For more information on the statistical-side see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67551/calculate-mean-of-ordinal-variable).